# rsyslog stopped forwarding httpd logs after logrotate

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, redhat-enterprise-linux, logrotate

I have an issue where rsyslog stops forwarding httpd logs to our central log repo after logrotate.  Server is RHEL7.  My investigations thus far have led me here:

```
(in /var/lib/rsyslog)
#:  grep httpd * |grep access |awk -F: '{print $1":"$2}' |xargs ls -ltr
-rw-------. 1 root root 103 Jul 14 11:35 imfile-state:137457168
-rw-------. 1 root root 103 Jul 14 11:42 imfile-state:137457173
-rw-------. 1 root root 103 Jul 19 03:20 imfile-state:137457170
-rw-------. 1 root root 101 Jul 27 12:40 imfile-state:137457166
# ls -i /var/log/httpd/access.log
137457166 /var/log/httpd/access.log
```

So, the rsyslog imfile-state:inode file does exist for the httpd access log.  Viewing the file gives me the offset that rsyslog uses so that it doesn't resend old data on restart.

```
#: cat  imfile-state:137457166
{ "filename": "\/var\/log\/httpd\/access.log", "prev_was_nl": 0, "curr_offs": 8305123, "strt_offs": 8305123 }
```

But, when I open the /var/log/httpd/access.log using vim and enter :goto 8305123, it takes me to the last character in the file which suggests it hasn't yet reached that number (further backed up by the fact that the new file is much smaller than this number suggests).  So it appears that after logrotate has run, rsyslog is picking up that there is a new log file to follow but is recording the last byte position of the old log file into the new imfile-state:inode file.

As the new /var/log/httpd/access.log file is starting at zero bytes, rsyslog stops forwarding any lines from this log until it contains enough content to reach and subsequently surpass the byte position in the imfile-state: file.

The logrotate conf file for httpd is:

```
/var/log/httpd/*log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    delaycompress
    postrotate
        /bin/systemctl reload httpd.service > /dev/null 2>/dev/null || true
    endscript
}
```

and from the last 3 lines in the newly rotated /var/log/messages.1, I can see that rsyslog is HUP'ped immediately after the httpd.service is reloaded:

```
2020-07-26T03:26:02.912066+09:30 <hostname> systemd: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
2020-07-26T03:26:02.982370+09:30 <hostname> systemd: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
2020-07-26T03:26:03.088887+09:30 <hostname> rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.24.0-41.el7_7.2" x-pid="61518" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed
```

rsyslog version: rsyslog-8.24.0-41.el7_7.2.x86_64

I'm tearing my hair out trying to figure this one out.  Other log files have virtually identical config for logrotate and rsyslog and they continue unabated after rotate.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.